# How to move a bitmap (like long green grass moving by the wind) fixing its pivot at the bottom center point of the bitmap in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

In my application,I have a long green grass bitmap.I have to fix the bitmap so that it does not move its  bottom part and it should be placed at the left bottom corner of the screen.So i have to fix its pivot at the bottom center of the bitmap.After that i should move the bitmap (like grass moving by the wind) to its left,some pixels and to its right,some pixels distance.But the bitmap should not move its pivot position.I am unable to fix the pivot position and to achieve the grass moving.I am posting the code which i have done.Please help me to solve this.

```
        private float direction = 1;
          private float mangle = 0;
  Bitmap green_1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.green_1);

      private void drawPaper(Canvas canvas){    
      Paint paint=new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

        if (mangle >= 3) {
            direction=-0.2f;
        } else if (mangle<=-3) {
            direction=0.2f;
        }
        mangle = mangle + direction;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postTranslate(0,heightOfCanvas-green_1.getHeight());
        matrix.postTranslate(0, mangle);


        canvas.drawBitmap(green_1, matrix, paint);
       }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just rotate the canvas using :

```
canvas.rotate(deg, xpivot, ypivot)
```

See : [Canvas#rotate(float, float, float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate%28float,%20float,%20float%29)

Comment: I tried but could not get it.If possible can u please just tell me  the changes in my written code